# CCArray with CCSprites in Cocos2D/Kobold2D

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone, kobold2d

I am developing a Cocos2D/Kobold2D game with ARC. I want to store CCSprite references in a CCArray. All the CCSprite objects are added as children to a parent CCNode. Is it a good idea to wrap the CCSprite objects with [NSValue valueWithNonretainedObject:..] for weak references? In all examples I found the CCSprites were stored retained in CCArrays...

Answer (score 0):

There is really no need to use NSValue.

If you add objects to an NSArray or CCArray or any collection, they will be retained. It is your duty to make sure the objects are removed respectively the collection released at the appropriate time.

In many cases you don't actually need to store node references separately. You have the children array, just iterate over it and select the nodes you need to work with, for example by tagging them or by using the userObject property.